# Parsing String to Object

Tags: java, string, parsing, split

I am having trouble parsing a String into an object.
I want to be able to take a String such as : "John Smith 1234" and parse it into a Person object (Person(String, String, int) )

To do this, I first tried turning the String into a String[] and splitting at the spaces.
I can't figure out why this isn't working- I tried testing just this part of the method and I got this: [Ljava.lang.String;@1aa8c488

Here is my code:

```
public static Person parseToPerson(String s) {
    String first = "";
String last = "";
String ID = "";
String[] splitArray = s.split("\\s+");
splitArray[0] = first;
splitArray[1] = last;
splitArray[2] = ID;
System.out.println(splitArray);
return new Person(first, last, Integer.parseInt(ID));
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't figure out why this isn't working

You should swap your assignments :

```
first = splitArray[0];
last = splitArray[1];
ID = splitArray[2];
```

---

> I tried testing just this part of the method and I got this:
>   [Ljava.lang.String;@1aa8c488

Since `splitArray` is an array, you see the string representation of the array itself and not the content of it. Use [`Arrays.#toString(java.lang.Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've swapped the assignments. Try this.

```
first = splitArray[0];
last = splitArray[1];
ID = splitArray[2];
```

You are not getting the output that you'd like though because you should use the `Arrays.toString(splitArray)` to output the array:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

like this...

```
public static Person parseToPerson(String s) {
    String first = "";
    String last = "";
    String ID = "";
    String[] splitArray = s.split("\\s+");
    first = splitArray[0];
    last = splitArray[1];
    ID = splitArray[2];
    System.out.println(splitArray);
    return new Person(first,last, Integer.parseInt(ID));
}
```